# Executing only tests using pytest without executing parent script

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, python-unittest

How do I just run the tests without executing the parent script in py.test? Currently I run command `pytest -v` from directory Project_dir, and this runs *script.py* and tests finally in the end. Ideally only tests need to be run. Here is my current directory setup:

```
Project_dir
    script.py
    test
        test_script.py
```

**script.py**

```
def add(a,b):
    added = a + b
    return added

x = add(1,3)
print x, 'yup'
```

**test_script.py**

```
import script

def test_add():
    assert script.add(3,4) == 7
```

*Working directory:* Project_dir

*Command:* pytest -vs

```
========================================== test session starts ==========================================
platform darwin -- Python 2.7.10, pytest-3.0.7, py-1.4.33, pluggy-0.4.0 -- /usr/bin/python
cachedir: .cache
rootdir: **, inifile:
plugins: cov-2.4.0
collecting 0 items
Sum is 4
collected 1 items

test/test_script.py::test_add PASSED

======================================= 1 passed in 0.00 seconds ========================================
```

`Sum is 4` shows the *script.py* executed fully instead of just the tests. It happens as the *script.py* is imported as module. But I keep thinking there must be a way to avoid this and just execute the tests directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Importing a module in Python executes all top-level code in it.

You should have your code in a `if __name__ == '__main__':` so it only executes when you run your script (but not when you import it) - see e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/419185/2085149) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Try to [Ignore paths during test collection](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/pythoncollection.html)

```
pytest -v --ignore=script.py
```

Or run pytest on a directory:

```
pytest -v test/
```

See [Specifying tests / selecting tests](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/usage.html#specifying-tests-selecting-tests)

Comment: You can run pytest on a directory

Comment: Still executes the main script. Not sure if `pytest -v` is any different from `pytest -v test/` since we have only one test directory here. Just to be clear, main script gets executed when it is imported as module in the test script.

Answer (score 0):

How about running `pytest test/`? 
Just to make it clear:
https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/usage.html#specifying-tests-selecting-tests

```
pytest somepath      # run all tests below somepath
```

Comment: Meaning `pytest test_script.py` for my example? It's not different (except for verbose) from `pytest -v` as pytest uses discovery rules to do the same thing.

Comment: So.. you want to test some script behaviour, without executing it? How do you test it then? :) I guess you should show us `test_script.py` and `scripts.py` if possible.

Comment: I am not sure if it's possible or not. Added an example now. Thanks!